# Will my ember app work in IE browser if I update it from 2.18 to 3.4?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

The current version of my ember app is `2.18.0` and the app is working to `IE` browser as well and if I upgrade it to `3.4` would it not run to `IE`? If not, what are the versions of `IE` that it won't run?

Is it possible to support the `IE` version that are lower than `9` for ember version `3.14`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Ember 3.x works in IE 11 as long as you configure your app's targets with that browser.  This configuration is handled in `config/targets.js`. The default version can be found at:

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/blueprints/app/files/config/targets.js

and looks like

```
'use strict';

const browsers = [
  'last 1 Chrome versions',
  'last 1 Firefox versions',
  'last 1 Safari versions'
];

const isCI = !!process.env.CI;
const isProduction = process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'production';

if (isCI || isProduction) {
  browsers.push('ie 11');
}

module.exports = {
  browsers
};
```

The separate production/CI section allows development to happen with the much easier to reason about async/await syntax, but the final production build is modified to work with IE.

The full list of possible browser targets can be found at https://browserl.ist/

For example: [last 1 Firefox versions](https://browserl.ist/?q=last%201%20Firefox%20versions)

Comment: Hi @jrjohnson thank you for your answer but what is the `CI`?

Comment: Also, do I need to specify what are the version of IE that will work? Can I just put `browsers.push('ie')` and will support all the version of `IE`?

Comment: CI is an environmental variable automatically set by services like TravisCI and CircleCI (and probably others). You made need to change it depending on your testing setup, but it tells the tests to run against the same code as production for safety.  Versions of IE before 11 are not officially supported and probably won't work, but it wouldn't be a good idea to support them anyway as Microsoft dropped support for all versions before 11 a few years ago https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support and they are no longer secure.

Comment: I added a link to https://browserl.ist/ which you can use to see what browsers any specific setting here will give you.

Comment: Thank you @jrjhonson for the help I appreciated it. :)